# Why does jquery not (always) work with multiple ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I'm a jquery newbie and I managed to get together the following script to have a div sliding up from below that disappears when clicking on a "X":

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

  $('#spendenbanner-schliessen').click(function(){
    $('#spendenbanner').slideUp();
    var date = new Date();
    var m = 5; /* Make cookie expire after m minutes */
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie('noSpende', '1', { expires: date, path: '/' });
  });

  if($.cookie('noSpende') > null) {
    $('#spendenbanner').hide();
  }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('#spendenbanner-schliessen').click(function(){
    $('#spendenbanner').slideUp();
    var date = new Date();
    var m = 5; /* Make cookie expire after m minutes */
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie('noSpende', '1', { expires: date, path: '/' });
  });

  if($.cookie('noSpende') > null) {
    $('#spendenbanner').hide();
  }
});
```

As you can see, I already duplicated the code because one only works without ajax and the other one with ajax. The HTML is something like the following:

```
<div id="spendenbanner">
  <div class="spendenbanner-text">
    <div id="spendenbanner-schliessen">X</div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does work with the mentioned duplication. But as soon as I have another ajax block on the page, clicking on the "X" doesn't have any effect. Could somebody help me with that problem? I have spent hours and hours, but I wasn't able to figure out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Drupal.behaviors ->

```js
Drupal.behaviors.blockSlide = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#spendenbanner-schliessen').click(function(){
          $('#spendenbanner').slideUp();
          var date = new Date();
          var m = 5; /* Make cookie expire after m minutes */
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
          $.cookie('noSpende', '1', { expires: date, path: '/' });
        });
        
      if($.cookie('noSpende') > null) {
        $('#spendenbanner').hide();
      }    
  }
};
```

Additionally i totally recommend reading this: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal

Behaviours works much better with Ajax calls in Drupal :)

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. But I haven't been able to get it to work, there's just no effect and the debugger tells me "TypeError: this is not a function" as soon as I use the code above (also without the cookie part). I keep trying..

Answer (score -1):

This myight be because of you are trying to bind click event with dynamic element created from ajax response. To over come this you can either use "on" or "live" handler to bind the element and event only once.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", '#spendenbanner-schliessen', function() { 

    $('#spendenbanner').slideUp();
    var date = new Date();
    var m = 5; /* Make cookie expire after m minutes */
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie('noSpende', '1', { expires: date, path: '/' });
  });

  if($.cookie('noSpende') > null) {
    $('#spendenbanner').hide();
  }
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('#spendenbanner-schliessen').live("click", function(){
    $('#spendenbanner').slideUp();
    var date = new Date();
    var m = 5; /* Make cookie expire after m minutes */
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie('noSpende', '1', { expires: date, path: '/' });
  });

  if($.cookie('noSpende') > null) {
    $('#spendenbanner').hide();
  }
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: .live was removed from jquery in 1.9 you should not use it

Comment: @pete: yes live() is deprecated, but if you are using older version then it is  best to use live()

Comment: it's not just deprecated it's been removed and you don't state use it in an older version - you just say use it, so if OP used it in a newer version, it would not work and they would not know why.  Also if someone is using jquery 1.7 or earlier, then they have more problems than just using an old function